# What is the possible methods to keep application configuration information while developing bloomberg application with C#?

Tags: configuration, app-config, bloomberg, blpapi

What is the possible ways to keep application configuration information while developing bloomberg application with C# ?
I think one of them is using PersistenceService static class (Bloomberglp.AppPortalApi.DataPersistence.PersistenceService) which keeps information as name-value pair.
I'd like to keep a list of data related to one name. Is it possible to solve this problem using local database ? However local database doesn't work in bloomberg anywhere.
Configuration set-up file or XML file might be used, but Bloomberg doesn't allow to access file system through application.

Comment: "*local database doesn't work in bloomberg anywhere*" => why not? As long as you don't send the data outside the machine where it was fetched it should be fine, no?

Comment: It is written in the document: Bloomberg Application Portal g Started v2.8 | December 3, 2012.
*The local database functionality is not supported when end user is logged in via Bloomberg Anywhere (Bloomberg.com). That application should check property BlpEnvironment.IsTerminalServiceEnvironment first and avoid using local database if property is set to TRUE.

Comment: @assylias, you are talking about the client API v3 while the question is about developing a third party application to be sold on the "Bloomberg App Store"

Comment: @ytoledano indeed that is where the confusion lies.

Comment: you should be able to use embedded file if you need it only for reading config information